# How to create custom token in substrate

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

How to create custom token in substrate in compliance with ERC20, for example custom tokens can be named as

1. Quanta American Dollars
2. Quanta British Pound.
3. Quanta Rupees
4. Quanta Euros
5. Quanta Yen

Comment: Make sure to check this answer from the Substrate Exchange: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5545/3796

Answer (score 3):

A good way to start for creating a custom token is hacking with the **balances pallet** https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/71e66bf606c0eb9d461e347ada46897f3d60c47b/frame/balances

If what you find inside is a little bit strange for you, you can always go to the great substrate documentation and start getting your hands on this! https://substrate.dev/docs/en/

EDIT: some more color on this!
I completely missed this when answering you, but maybe the **asset pallet** could be what makes that *click* with the idea you have
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/71e66bf606c0eb9d461e347ada46897f3d60c47b/frame/assets

Also, if balances nor asset pallets adapts to what you are exactly looking for, you can always build you own! What basically is one of the huge advantages of building with substrate and FRAME.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But could you please through light on configuring different cross currency like Dollar / Euro etc,.  for the same token.

Comment: For that I personally think that you should go with some kind of oracle system, offchain workers could be handy for you in this case

https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/learn-substrate/off-chain-features